# Why did the male Pigeon say "The heart of a hawk" three times?

Tags: doctor-dolittle, dr-dolittle-1998

Funny fantasy movie *Dr.Dolittle (1998)*

At the zoo, two talking pigeons overhear voices of the Cop who is trying to catch the catnapper, Dr.Dolittle by running a license plate number:

> Cop: Yeah, I got a plate ID on the catnapper.
>
> Female Pigeon: Do something.
>
> Male Pigeon: **The heart of a hawk! The heart of a hawk! The heart of a
>   hawk!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a reference to an earlier line where he was told that **a pigeon is a pigeon and nothing more**.

> *"You're not a robin. Or a dove **or a hawk.** You're a pigeon and I'm a pigeon."*

Pigeons don't usually hover, they're not normally helpful and they most certainly don't (normally) do brave things *unless they've got the heart of a hawk*, like we might say that a human had the heart of a lion.

The film's [official novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/91546.Doctor_Dolittle) confirms this.

> "*The heart of a hawk, the heart of a hawk*," the male pigeon repeated
> to himself, **feeling the words giving him courage**. He flew off over San
> Francisco. When he spotted the police horse on the streets below, the
> pigeon landed on a nearby trash can.